# A given ring of matrices has an infinite number of invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

The set $\mathcal{M} = \bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & 2b \\ b & a \\ \end{pmatrix} \bigg\vert  a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \bigg\}$ is given. Prove that:

(1) $\mathcal{M}$ is a commutative ring with respect to addition and multiplication

(2) An element is invertible in $\mathcal{M}$ if and only if $\vert a^2-2b^2 \vert=1$.

(3) $\mathcal{M}$ has an infinite number of invertible elements.

I have solved points (1) and (2), but I have no idea how to solve (3). Any hints?

Comment: Hint: use [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation). "The equation $a^2-2b^2=1$ has been studied as early as 400 BC in India and Greece".

Answer (score 3):

If $a=3$ and $b=2$, then $a^2-2b^2=1$. In particular $(3+2\sqrt{2})(3-2\sqrt{2})=1$. Consider
$$
x_n=(3+2\sqrt{2})^n=a_n+b_n\sqrt{2},\quad y_n=(3-2\sqrt{2})^n.
$$
What can you say about $a_n$, $b_n$ and $a_n^2-2b_n^2$? (Use that $x_ny_n=1$).

---

You can note that the map
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a & 2b \\ b & a\end{bmatrix}
\mapsto
a+b\sqrt{2}
$$
is a ring isomorphism from $\mathcal{M}$ onto $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, so the invertible elements are in bijection.

Comment: That's a nice solution, never would have thought of it!

Comment: @AlexanderSmith This is the idea of solving Pell's equation. Of course, Slade's solution is *exactly* the same idea, though he/she claims it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to bring any outside information about Pell's equation.  Just take some non-trivial unit, say $x = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 3 \\ \end{pmatrix}$, and observe that elements $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ are distinct.

In fact, the $x$ generates the group of units, but that is not necessary here.

Comment: Instead of «bringing outside» information you invoked the gods to tell you a solution of infinite order — and they probably used the solution of Pell's equation to find it...